# Android notifications delay

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm making a notification in android, but I have a small delay before the notification appears - is this normal? Here is my code:

```
final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;         
Intent intent = new Intent(Add_Assignment.this, Assignment_AlarmReceiver.class);
//Bundle stuff omitted for brevity
PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
      PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Add_Assignment.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);


AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
           System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(Add_Assignment.this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Can't find info anywhere. Notifications generally show up as soon as i unlock my phone. Same is true if i just play a ring tone. It's delayed until unlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000)` means `5` `seconds` from `now`.

Comment: Yes, sorry - my bad question. I meant to ask why I'm getting a larger delay - of anywhere between 5 seconds to 2 mins. The alarm is a notification, would you like me to post that code too?